# While hosting at major players like AWS or Azure or Google Cloud, can I trust that my code and table structures wont be copied?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, security, google-cloud-platform, hosting

I am new bee with this question.
**Thus, if you don't want to up-vote the question, atleast, don't negatively mark the question, thinking it is not about tech.

For me it is about technology as it is about security of code.**
I already have a website.
My idea is unique and thus I am more concerned about my code's privacy.
Off course, even local hosting providers will be least interested in, what has been hosted, until they come to know the growth of the company. But what about, that I think my idea will over take "google", while, for today, I am no where in the world?
More over the code is in PHP (no dll like thing).
As any hosting company has full access to the server, they can easily copy the entire code and do whatever they want?
Whom can I trust?
Trust totally, in sense that my code will never be copied or leaked.
I want to host my code with a company that is totally reliable.

While I don't have trust in local hosting providers, my question is that can I trust major players like aws or azure or google cloud?
Or is there something else that I must do?

Comment: dont think that this is a tech question. trust issues, sometimes, you just have to make the jump. unless you are doing something illegal, you can trust them.

Comment: Consider that AWS, Azure, and Google all have written code that is now running the entire world. They probably aren't interested in whatever you're doing, anyhow.

Comment: Source code by itself has little value to most companies today. There is so much open source available that anything you think of has probably already been published. For those rare cases where your code is original, a company would be more interested in hiring your developers than stealing from you. If you have something really hot, they will just write a check. I have extensive security experience with the four major clouds. I back up my source code, documents, etc to the cloud. I don't give it a second thought.

Comment: For the naysayers, there is a good rule. If you want to keep something secret, do not tell anyone that you even have a secret. In that case, you will want to self-host on your own internal servers connected with dedicated business class Internet. You will encrypt everything including your backups. Since you cannot trust anyone, even your own memory, how will you remember the encryption keys, where will you store your backups, how will you police your employees. The list goes on and on.

Comment: @jay, if you think this isn't tech issue, i don't think, you think about security, at all.
and you shouldn't be on this question at all (and probably negatively voting it).
i seek answers from those who have already thought about this and have concrete answers.
off course, even local hosting providers will be least interested in, what has been hosted, until they come to know the growth of the company.
but what about my idea, that i think will over take "google", while, for today, i am no where in the world?

Comment: No one's criticizing you for having a dream. But having your code copied by your host should be **way** down toward the bottom of your list of concerns. Google happily accepts green money from many of their competitors to host their infrastructure on GCP. And if they ever tried to decrypt the data (which they can't), they'd be sued into oblivion.

Comment: @urkoruche (no man, I did not negative vote this stuff but I just did after you pointed it out, he he :P ) to each his own. I trust Microsoft (I work on Azure) just like I trust my bank or doctor and so on. Its a silly logic but that is my way of looking at it. you got trust issues with your hosting provider, that's your deal. I don't think about security - in this context - because I don't own any proprietary code. when I work for a client, I let them handle it through their lawyers. Tomorrow, when I built something I own, I will let my lawyers deal with it.

Comment: @jay, the great intellect, any way, may god bless you for negative-voting my question.

Comment: @urkoruche he he :P high praise man ;)

Comment: Some of the downvotes likely are also related to the haphazard formatting and unreadableness of your question.

Answer (score 4):

> trust totally, in sense that my code will never be copied or leaked.

The largest companies in the world trust these big cloud providers to keep their data safe and secure, and to reliably run large parts of their [multi-billion dollar businesses](https://cloud.google.com/customers/#/). Millions of servers, thousands upon thousands of petabytes of data, billions in revenue. **If Google Cloud is good enough for companies like The Mayo Clinic, Paypal, Ebay, and Chevron, it's probably good enough for you.**

> as any hosting company has full access to the server, they can easily copy the entire code and do whatever they want?

No they cannot. In the case of Google Cloud, data is encrypted at rest by default. And in the case of the other major providers (Google, AWS, Azure), no human has access to your machines unless you explicitly give them access to help you with something.

Google clearly lays out their [data security policies](https://cloud.google.com/security/privacy/). These policies form part of the shared responsibility between you and the provider.

> or is there something else that i must do?

At the end of the day, you have to trust someone. You'll have servers and chips that you didn't design, on a network you didn't build, in a datacenter you don't own. You're better off putting your trust in a big company with a reputation to uphold -- and who you can sue -- than an unknown entity.

Comment: thank you.
It is satisfying.
But i will wait for some more time to get other answers/ideas.
thank you once again.

Comment: "In the case of Google Cloud, data is encrypted at rest by default." It should be noted that it's generally encrypted via keys *under Google's control*. They *can* read the info on a technical level, but doing so would be a death knell to their multi-billion dollar business if they got found out doing it. As such, they've got lots of controls in place to prevent a single bad actor from doing bad things.

Comment: Yes, you'd first have to get access to the keys (which very few humans have access to), find the particular key that decrypts his particular instance, and then decrypt. Keep in mind that access to all these things is monitored by the rest of the system, so you'd have to do all that without getting caught.